Using querySelector in Typescript: why does it accept HTMLElement return type?
querySelector can return any subtype of Element. On a webpage this would almost certainly be either HTMLElement or SVGElement. The two are not compatible, and yet TypeScript seems happy for me to assign the result of querySelector to an HTMLElement type and access properties specific to HTMLElement. Why doesn't it throw an error?
Here's an example
// why no error on assuming it's going to be HTMLELement
// and not SVGELement or some other Element?
const foo: HTMLElement | null = document.querySelector("*");

if (foo !== null) {
    console.log(foo.hidden);
}

This compiles fine, however foo can actually be an SVGElement.
If I manually set foo's type to be SVGElement then typescript will rightfully complain about accessing the hidden property.
Why doesn't TypeScript catch the mistaken assumption that the return of querySelector is necessarily an HTMLElement?

The signature for the method is
querySelector<E extends Element = Element>(selectors: string): E | null;

By defining the returned type as HTMLElement (see Type Inference), you've provided the E generic type. Your code is the equivalent of
const foo = document.querySelector<HTMLElement>('*'); // HTMLElement | null

The only restriction is that E must extend Element.

Thanks, so what you're saying is that I am making the assertion that it will return an HTMLELement (even though the * could very well match an SVGElement) and TypeScript is happy with it? But in the generated JavaScript, querySelector('*') could return a non HTMLElement and then accessing HTMLElement-specific properties on it could result in an error... I would have thought that TypeScript would at least warn about that. Am I misunderstanding?

That's right. This is one of those times where you're basically telling the compiler that you know best. It won't prevent runtime issues though

Nothing wrong about typescript.
From lib.dom.d.ts for definition querySelector (access by hold ctrl + mouse click on function name with good IDE)
We will found.
...
querySelector<E extends Element = Element>(selectors: string): E | null;
...

mean querySelector is Generic and default is  Element type. It will return Element if we didn't explicit them.
and we could explicit generic's arguments.
const foo = document.querySelector<SVGElement>("*");//this will return SVGElement | null

if (foo) {
   //use foo as SVGElement 
}

or by generic's argument deduction (don't know how to call in typescript but in c++ has similar one)
const foo:SVGElement | null = document.querySelector("*");//typescript will inference to document.querySelector<SVGElement>("*")

if (foo) {
   //use foo as SVGElement 
}

So the reason that you get HTMLElement because Typescript does infer type from const foo: HTMLElement | null to document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("*").

@Phil Yes. and my answer seem misleading. so I did updated them already.
